# Alter field items before render

Tags: entities, javascript

I'd like to add an item to a multivalued image field rendered by the [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module.
I need to display an image coming from field image B of entity B in the slideshow of field image A of entity A.
The Field Slideshow module implements [hook_field_formatter_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7).
I'd like to be able to add an item at the end of the $items variable of this function.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone comes here, use [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)

In template.php :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_myfield') {
    //Load the related node, I let you do this step ...
    //$nid = ...

    $nodeB = node_load($nid);
    $variables['items'][0]['#items'][] = $nodeB->field_another_image_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
    //If you have a pager
    $variables['items'][0]['#pager']['#items'][] = $nodeB->field_another_image_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hook you're looking for is hook_field_prepare_view https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_prepare_view/7

It runs before hook_field_formatter_view().

Comment: I tried hook_field_prepare_view and hook_field_formatter_prepare_view. They were never triggered. I put them in my module, maybe I'll try in my template.php file. Also, I did find a workaround by using MYTHEME_ecommerce_preprocess_field

Comment: Ah, you're right. hook_field_prepare_view() is one of those many field related hooks available only to the module that declares the field type. Another place where Drupal (pre Drupal 8) implements object oriented concepts with PHP 4 era methodology.